# How to convert time in H:M:S to decimal minutes?

Tags: r, time

I have a table that has the following set of numbers:

```
Time in Hours Used
  1:05:34
  1:04:45
  1:12:04
    34:17
    43:35
```

... for fifty five observations

How can I create a new column with the time in hours being listed as minutes. I know I can multiply it by 24*60 but for some reason when I do this, it says that factors can't be multiplied.

I have tried other programs like `chronos` but they would require me to literally input every single value and create a vector of values for all 55 observations. How can I just multiply each one of these values by 24*60 to get them in minute?

Comment: If it is `H:M:S` format, why are you multiplying by 24 * 60? Multiply the hours by 60, then add the minutes surely? You don't have a day in there do you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `guess_formats` from `lubridate` to get the multiple formats in the dataset column, use that in `parse_date_time` to convert to date time class.  We extract the time part (`%H:%M:%S`) with `format`, convert to `times` class using `times` from `chron`, and then we multiply with 24*60 after converting to `numeric`.

```
library(chron)
library(lubridate)
as.numeric(times(format(parse_date_time(df1[,1],guess_formats(df1[,1], 
                  c('hms', 'ms'))), '%H:%M:%S')))*24*60
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(timeinhours = structure(c(2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L),
.Label = c("1:04:45", "1:05:34", "1:12:04", "34:17", "43:35"),
class = "factor")), .Names = "timeinhours", row.names = c(NA, -5L),
class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: As I note above, why multiply by 24 * 60? That converts days to minutes, not hours to minutes.

Comment: @thelatemail I don't know, just coding it based on what the OP described.

Comment: @thelatemail  `times` expresses the `H:M:S` as a fraction of the day (i.e. 24 hours). Thus, `as.numeric(times("12:00:00"))` gives `0.5`. `0.5 * 24` gives `12`in hours. And `12 * 60` gives `720` in minutes.